# How to replace marker in TCA with itemsProcFunc?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have a marker in TCA I want to replace this with the current UID.

The TCA code like this

```
'foreign_table' => 'pages',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'AND groups = ###UID###',
                'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
                'itemsProcFunc' => 'Vendor\\extkey\\Utility\\GeneralUtility->render',
```

My render function look like this:

```
/**
     *
     * @param array $PA
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\FormEngine $pObj
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(array &$PA, $pObj) {
        $uid = $PA['row']['uid'];
        $PA['config']['foreign_table_where'] = str_replace('###UID###', $uid, $PA['config']['foreign_table_where']);
        return $PA;

    }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you doing this so complexe?

Look at the [TCAReference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/singlehtml/Index.html#foreign-table-where). There is allready an marker `###THIS_UID###` which is replaced with the uid of the current element. So your configuration can look like this:

```
'foreign_table' => 'pages',
'foreign_table_where' => 'AND groups = ###THIS_UID###',
'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
```

Also have a look at the description: `is current element uid (zero if new)`. If your element is new you don't have any uid.

Comment: Thx for the hint. I see already in the docs but i overlooked.